# Functionality of button color and gradient

Tags: android, android-button, rounded-corners

I saw links about Rounded Button in Android and gradient, but combination of gradient and the button color (solid android:color="#3f5063")do not work together.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
  <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FF404040" />
  <solid android:color="#3f5063" />
  <corners
   android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
   android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
   android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
   android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>
  <gradient android:startColor="#FF6800" android:centerColor="#FF8000" android:endColor="#FF9700" android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

Comment: show what you want to get. Gradient and solid fills whole shape, so you use one of them

Comment: So should we use one of the two? I thought the two could be used together. Thank you for your answer.